# I got a probelm using PreviewView with CameraX?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, preview, android-camerax

The PreviewView shrink to half of the screen even if I change `AspectRatio` from `AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9` to `AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3` !!

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        previewView = view.findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
  

        setCameraProviderListener();

    }
```

```
private void setCameraProviderListener() {
        ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture =
                ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext());
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {

            try {
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                bindPreview(cameraProvider);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                // No errors need to be handled for this Future
                // This should never be reached
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()));
    }
```

```
 private void bindPreview(ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {
        
 previewView.setPreferredImplementationMode(PreviewView.ImplementationMode.SURFACE_VIEW);

        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3).
                setTargetRotation(previewView.getDisplay().getRotation())
                .build();


        CameraSelector cameraSelector =
                new CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build();

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider());

        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector,preview);

    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/preview_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/Yellow"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my code I was facing this problem for 2 months!!
The `PreviewView` is wrapped in a `LinearLayout` with yellow as a `background` color, but when the camera start it just show in the top half of the `PreviewView` and the `PreviewView` turn black.

Comment: Can you share code for how your layout looks, and how you change the aspect ratio. Also, does this happen across many devices, or only on a specific one?

Comment: I change aspect ration by the code above and the layout it's so simple `LinearLayout` with `PreviewView` inside it

Comment: and yes it happens across many emulators devices and different android versions

Comment: Maybe you can share you project on GitHub "as is", because it all looks correct to me, and very similar code shows full screen preview on my device. Also, please disclose which device you are testing: there may be weird bugs on some phones, CameraX currently supports only ~90% of all thousands of existing device models.

Comment: I tested in various devices like Pixel 3, Pixel 3 XL, Nexus 5X (emulators) and S7 real device all show the same thing

Comment: I copy-paste the code in a new project with a single activity, not a fragment and the code work fine !!!!?

Comment: OK, so the problem is somewhere in your fragment management which is out-of-scope for this question. I would suggest to simply close this question, and possibly open a separate one, about the fragment layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer it's a little bit tricky

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a snippet I wrote to test the issue you described, but I wasn't able to reproduce it.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
        val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
        bindPreview(cameraProvider, unbindAll = false)
        previewView.setOnClickListener {
            bindPreview(cameraProvider)
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()))
}

private var aspectRatio = AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3
private fun getAndUpdateAspectRatio(): Int {
    val currentAspectRation = aspectRatio
    aspectRatio = if (aspectRatio == AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3) {
        AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9
    } else {
        AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3
    }
    return currentAspectRation
}

private fun bindPreview(cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider, unbindAll: Boolean = true) {
    val preview = Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetAspectRatio(getAndUpdateAspectRatio())
            .setTargetRotation(previewView.display.rotation)
            .build()

    previewView.preferredImplementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.SURFACE_VIEW
    preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider())

    if (unbindAll) {
        cameraProvider.unbindAll()
    }
    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner, CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA, preview)
}
```

This code lives inside a `Fragment` whose layout contains a `PreviewView` wrapped in a `LinearLayout`. I tested this on a Pixel 3 XL and a Nokia 1. Could you test it and see if it fails on your device(s)?

Also, the code uses the latest versions of CameraX, meaning camera-camera2 version 1.0.0-beta07, and camera-view version 1.0.0-alpha14.

Comment: I use java in my project can you check my code I made an edit.